# How can i remove only brackets that has only string not special Characters

Tags: python, regex

Here is my text

```
(he needs to buy him an) [/-] (.) this rabbit <I> [/] is (..) woke  up (...) (be)cause he needs to go home with his father .
```

Desired Output is

```
he needs to buy him an [/-] (.) this rabbit <I> [/] is (..) woke    up (...) because he needs to go home with his father .
```

Comment: Have you tried any Python code yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if i know the regex to be used i can proceed with python code

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: re.sub(r'\([a-z].*?\)',"",newline) . But this is removing the texts also inside the bracket

Comment: Try my code by using Positive Lookahead `(?= )` and Positive Lookbehind `(?<= )` , and see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\((?=[A-z])|(?<=[A-z])\)
```

I used both Positive Lookahead `(?= )` and Positive Lookbehind `(?<= )` to match the brackets that has string inside them.

- Positive Lookahead `(?= )`
- Positive Lookbehind `(?<= )`
- `[A-z]` to match only strings

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/pc3JDu/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, which makes two calls to `re.sub`:

```
input = "(he needs to buy him an) [/-] (.) this rabbit <I> [/] is (..) woke [BLAH] up (...) (be)cause he needs to go home with his father ."
output = re.sub(r'\[([A-Za-z0-9]+?)\]', '\\1', re.sub(r'\(([A-Za-z0-9]+?)\)', '\\1', input))
```

### Demo

This matches on either the pattern `\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\]` or `\(([A-Za-z0-9]+)\)`, and then replaces with just the content which was inside either the parentheses or square brackets.

Comment: Its removing all the brackets that has special characters too i.e (.) or (...)

Comment: @user1882624 The updated demo code never made it back into my answer.  Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub('\(\w\)', '', s)
```

's' - is your string

'\w'- regex that matches words